# Turning one column into a string in SQL

Tags: sql, string, coalesce

I have a table in SQL that look like this:

[image: img]

The issue is that I would like it to be displayed in this fashion:

```
Medication Review | Allergies, CAM, Diet Supp,
```

Having one presenting problem and all of the secondary problems in a single row instead of the way it is now.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: This is called "aggregate string concatenation".  You can google this term with whatever database you are using and find various solutions.

Comment: If you are using MySQL you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`, but that is not standard SQL so its not available everywhere. Also, `COALESCE` is poorly named (IMO) and is not what your looking for.

Comment: I think `PIVOT` may be helpful here also.  Gordon's approach works just as well.  Just adding options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.presenting_problem,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + t2.secondary_problem
          FROM tableName t2
          where t1.presenting_problem = t1.presenting_problem
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS secondary_problems
from tableName t1;
```